# How to convert a docker-compose file to kubernetes file(s)?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

Is there any easy way to convert a docker-compose.yml file to Kubernetes file(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original and most popular solution I've seen is [kompose](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose) which does exactly as you are asking, converts the compose yaml file into kubernetes yaml files.

If you want to continue working with a compose.yml file for compatibility with other systems, then docker recently open sourced their [compose on kubernetes](https://github.com/docker/compose-on-kubernetes) solution that integrates directly into kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

This [online tool](https://8gwifi.org/kube1.jsp) will translate your compose file equivalent Kubernetes resources

[image]